# Flutter Webview - User Has to Login Every Time

Tags: android, flutter, webview

I have a Android app that is completely Flutter Webview. If the user closes the application after logging in, he or she has to log in when he comes back. In the website that I showed as webview, the user would not normally be logged off unless he or she clicked the "logout" button. What should I do not to log off users unless they click the "logout" button, even if they close the application?

Answer (score 0):

fist did u have any checks so u can verify that particular user already logged in or not?

if not then after every successful login create some data in local storage

and every time someone visits the login page just check the local storage data available or not if available proceed with them auto-login if not then keep them on the login page

[local stroage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

or u can use cookies also
[JavaScript Cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

[you can read this blog for more information](https://deryatanriverdi.medium.com/how-to-user-localstorage-to-keep-user-logged-in-and-out-8fd1e6e46712)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Flutter Webview does not clear the cache by default. This may be due to the site you show as webview or a change you made.